# Unexpected results when converting a namespaced object to an array

Tags: php, oop, namespaces

I'm having unexpected results when converting a namespaced object to an array.

```
<?php

namespace package\test;

class Test {
    private $foo;
    private $bar;

}

$test = new Test();
$testArray = (array) $test;

var_dump($testArray);
```

and the output is

```
array
    '�package\test\Test�foo' => null
    '�package\test\Test�bar' => null
```

Not sure what those `�` characters are from the `var_dump`? I looked in the source and it appears to be `&#0;`. Basically what I need to do is trim the keys so it ends up being

```
array
    'foo' => null
    'bar' => null
```

but I'm not sure how to target those `�` characters with a regular expression to get rid of the part that I don't want? This is for PHP 5.3.3. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually don't need any regular expressions. You can do the following:

```
foreach ($testArray as $key => $value) {
    $pos = strrpos($key, chr(0)); // find the last null character
    if ($pos !== false) {
        $testArray[substr($key, $pos+1)] = $value;
        unset($testArray[$key]);
    }
}
```

Every character that cannot be displayed will be replaced with a black diamond (U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER) by the browser. So in this case it wouldn't even make sense to check for this particular substitute character.